# why loop iteration range given by keyboard count itself as an iteration?

Tags: java, string, loops, split, iteration

```
public class P7 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
        int range=scanner.nextInt();
        for(int i=1;i<=range;i++){
            String stringInput =scanner.nextLine();
            String[] total =stringInput.split("\\s");
            int length=total.length;
            System.out.println(length);
        } 
    }
}
```

If you input range as 3 it will print its length as 1. But first iteration should print the length after getting stringInput.
Moreover when you input range as a String, you will get **InputMismatchException**. Which is correct. So where is the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Comment: So.. what is your exact input ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Scanner.nextInt()` only consumes up to the number that you input and leaves the "\n" in the Scanner buffer.  You can clear that buffer by using `Scanner.next()` right after you call `Scanner.nextInt()`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StackOverflow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
        int range=scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.next();

        for(int i=1;i<=range;i++){
            String stringInput =scanner.nextLine();
            String[] total =stringInput.split("\\s");
            int length=total.length;
            System.out.println(length);
        }

        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Result:

```
3
The asdfj
2
asldkja sfaslkj asdfljk
3
asdfjk asdfjlkasdf alksjdf asdflkj
4
```